# What do I need to install another HDMI port on my desktop?

Tags: hdmi

I have a Gateway SX2802-07 desktop with Windows 7.  It has only one HDMI port - for the monitor.  I want to add another HDMI port to stream video to my HDTV.  I see 'video card' and 'PCI card' a lot but am unsure which one I should use.  Are they universal or is there one specific to my unit?  Or should I be doing something else?  Thank you.

Comment: I would use a HDMI KVM and just skip hooking up the keyboard and mouse.  This would allow you to switch just the monitor that would be used in theory.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot help with shopping for specific hardware here on SuperUser,  but this is what I can tell you.

Your system has "on board" graphics (built on the motherboard), but it also has a pci-e card slot where you could install a add in video card that has 2 hdmi out ports.

Below is the specs for your pci-e slot in your system, so look for a video card that will work in this slot and has 2 hdmi out ports. Low profile graphics cards are different than standard desktop cards, so be sure you buy one that can go into a low profile card slot.

> PCI Express® 2.0 ×16 **low-profile** graphics card support

[Source of pci specs](https://support.gateway.com/s/desktop/2009/gateway/sx/sx2802/SX2802sp2.shtml)